# Selecting an item of a drop-down menu with Splinter lib (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, splinter

I am working on a project and there's this problem I am facing.
I want to select an element from a dropdown list but can't find a way. I tried targeting the ID of the value but the problem in that is, the 3 letters in between the id changes every time we load the page.
and this code doesn't seem to work.

```
element = browser.find_by_id('select2-f_country-container').click()
browser.find_by_xpath('//*[@id="select2-f_country-result"]/ul/li[4]').click()
```

Thanks in advance.

The Container: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnyFi.jpg

The container code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrdyJ.jpg

The list code:https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZYFr.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function a pass the country name as text.

To handle dynamic element Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`()

```
def selectCountry(strcountry):
    browser.find_element_by_id('select2-f_country-container').click()
    WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//ul[@id="select2-f_country-results"]//li[text="{}"]'.format(strcountry)))).click()


selectCountry("Albania")
```

Please note you need to import following libraries

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

---

Sometimes element might not visible if so you can use following ocde.

```
def selectCountry(strcountry):
    browser.find_element_by_id('select2-f_country-container').click()
    element=WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//ul[@id="select2-f_country-results"]//li[text="{}"]'.format(strcountry))))
    element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
    element.click()

selectCountry("Albania")
```